# Form in wordpress using ajax javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I think there is something wrong with my javascript.

I have (html) form:

```
<html><form action="wp-content/themes/devwp-child/action_page.php" method="post">



<fieldset>
<input type="text" name="ime" placeholder="Ime *">
<input type="text" name="priimek" placeholder="Priimek *">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-poštni naslov*">
<input type="text" name="telefonska" placeholder="Telefonska številka">
<input type="text" name="podjetje" placeholder="Podjetje">
</fieldset>
<p id="izberi">IZBERI</p>
<fieldset>
<input type = "radio" name = "subject" value = "maths"> Maths
         <input type = "radio" name = "subject" value = "physics"> Physics
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<textarea name="field3" placeholder="Vaše želje"></textarea>
</fieldset>

<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
   <script src="main.js"</script>



    </html>
```

Then i have 2 files:
-main.js
-action_page.php

action_page.php code:

```
<?php

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $ime = strip_tags(trim($_POST["ime"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);

        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);


        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($ime) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "ptlabdoo@gmail.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

If form is properly full then it sends an email - that words fine; but if form is not full then i get:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /wp-content/themes/devwp-child/action_page.php on this server.
Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

main.js code:

```
$(function() {
    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#ajax-contact');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(form).submit(function(event) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();

   // Serialize the form data.
var formData = $(form).serialize();
});

});

// Submit the form using AJAX.
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    data: formData
})


.done(function(response) {
    // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
    $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
    $(formMessages).addClass('success');

    // Set the message text.
    $(formMessages).text(response);

    // Clear the form.
    $('#name').val('');
    $('#email').val('');
    $('#message').val('');
})


.fail(function(data) {
    // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
    $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
    $(formMessages).addClass('error');

    // Set the message text.
    if (data.responseText !== '') {
        $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
    } else {
        $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
    }
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why javascript does not work fine?

Comment: What does work fine mean? You PHP throws a 400 based on certain criteria. There sin't enough here to understand what is wrong.